# What is this blue-green bioluminescent jellyfish I saw at Aquarium of the Pacific?

Tags: species-identification, bioluminescence

I took this picture of an animal in the bioluminescent section of Aquarium of the Pacific in Long Beach, California, but I neglected to write down what it was.  I've searched the Aquarium's web site, but it doesn't appear to have information about the individual species on exhibit.  (Or else I just can't find it.)  I've also looked at Wikipedia and Google Images, but can't seem to find a creature that looks like this one.

I suspected it could be a jellyfish, and the answer below confirms that.  But I'd like to know what species of jellyfish it is.  (Either common name or scientific name.)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After sifting through even more images on Google Images, I think I have finally identified this as the flower hat jelly, *Olindias formosa*.  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_hat_jelly), [Monterey Bay Aquarium](http://www.montereybayaquarium.org/animal-guide/invertebrates/flower-hat-jelly))

The coloration looks different on those sites, but I think it's just a matter of lighting.

Comment: I think they probably have it under UV blacklight at the Aquarium of the Pacific. So it's probably not bioluminescence, but UV fluorescence,

Comment: Thanks for that tip!  I did some further research, and [this article](http://www.deepseanews.com/2014/07/outta-sight-jelly-babies-discovered-with-a-black-light/) seems to confirm your hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

That is a Jellyfish! :D

Someone else took a picture of that same Jellyfish:

http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/aquarium-of-the-pacific-long-beach?select=36BuiiqeN7OIFbowSDkPcw

Here is a picture from [an article about the exhibit's jelly fish](http://lbpost.com/life/2000006141-new-jellies-exhibits-at-the-aquarium-of-the-pacific-explore-the-lives-and-purpose-of-mysterious-gelatinous-creatures):

[image]

Source: [New Jellies Exhibit at Aquarium of the Pacific Explores the Mysterious Lives of These Gelatinous Sea Creatures](http://lbpost.com/life/2000006141-new-jellies-exhibits-at-the-aquarium-of-the-pacific-explore-the-lives-and-purpose-of-mysterious-gelatinous-creatures)

Comment: Thanks!  I'd suspected it might be a jellyfish, but I wasn't sure.  I'd still like to know exactly what kind of jellyfish it is.  Unfortunately, the linked article doesn't have captions on its pictures.